# Extending a Collection where the Element type is generic (Swift)

Tags: swift, generics

It's simple to extend a Collection type in swift to have a custom function for particular Element types:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let string: String
}

extension Set where Element == MyStruct {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({ $0.string == string }).first
    }
}
```

But suppose your Element type is generic?

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

struct MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol> {
    let string: String
}

// error on next line:
// error: expected '>' to complete generic argument list
// extension Set where Element == MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol> {
//                                                 ^
extension Set where Element == MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol> {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({ $0.string == string }).first
    }
}

// error on next line:
// error: use of undeclared type 'T' 
// extension Set where Element == MyGenericStruct<T> {
//                                                ^
extension Set where Element == MyGenericStruct<T> {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({ $0.string == string }).first
    }
}
```

It's unclear to me how to declare that my element is a generic.

Comment: There's a method for this already: `mySet.first(where: { $0.string = "foo" })`. It doesn't warrant its own extension, imo

Comment: There is no `MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>`  type. There is one type of  `MyGenericStruct` per possible value of `T`. These types are mutually completely unrelated, so you can treat them homogeneously like this

Comment: @Alexander This is a contrived example. My real world example is not so simple, and is not a simple `first(where:)`

Comment: @Alexander That was my suspicion. There are obvious workarounds to this (I'm doing a generic function right now), but wanted to see if there was a way of expressing this directly.

Comment: Could you post the method you wrote?

Comment: Sure can. I'll post as an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand the purpose, you probably need to have more implementation in your `protocol` and `structure`.

**First, element's protocol has to be hashable and equitable.**

```
protocol MyProtocol: Hashable, Equatable {
    var string: String { get }
}
```

**Therefore, `MyGenericStruct` will look like the following.**

```
struct MyGenericStruct: MyProtocol {
    let string: String
    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return string.hashValue
        }
    }

    static func ==(lhs: MyGenericStruct, rhs: MyGenericStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}
```

**Then, declare extension with constraints specified by a where clause for `MyProtocol`**

```
extension Set where Element: MyProtocol {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({$0.string == string}).first
    }
}
```

**Finally, let's do a test and see its result.**

```
// Example
let set: Set = [
    MyGenericStruct(string: "Watermelon"),
    MyGenericStruct(string: "Orange"),
    MyGenericStruct(string: "Banana")
]
let output = set.getFirstWith(string: "Orange")
print(output)
```

In my playground with Xcode 8, I can get `Optional(MyGenericStruct(string: "Orange"))` in log.

**`[UPDATED1]` To make an `Extension` on `Set<MyGenericStruct>` only:**

```
extension Set where Element == MyGenericStruct {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({$0.string == string}).first
    }
}
```

**`[UPDATED2]` In case to keep `MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>` declaration as stated is necessary, another approach to implement `Set` extension:**

```
protocol MyProtocol {

}

struct BaseStruct1: MyProtocol {

}

struct BaseStruct2: MyProtocol {

}

protocol ContainStringProtocol: Hashable {
    var string: String { get }
}

struct MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>: ContainStringProtocol {
    var string: String
    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return string.hashValue
        }
    }

    init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }

    static func ==(lhs: MyGenericStruct, rhs: MyGenericStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

extension Set where Element: ContainStringProtocol {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({$0.string == string}).first
    }
}

// Example
let set1: Set = [
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct1>(string: "Watermelon"),
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct1>(string: "Orange"),
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct1>(string: "Banana")
]
let output1 = set1.getFirstWith(string: "Orange")
print(output1!)

let set2: Set = [
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct2>(string: "Watermelon"),
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct2>(string: "Orange"),
    MyGenericStruct<BaseStruct2>(string: "Banana")
]
let output2 = set2.getFirstWith(string: "Orange")
print(output2!)
```

Comment: This is good. My real world code is more complex (sorry, can't post, it's proprietary), so this does not solve my problem exactly (i.e. it's important that the Set be Set<MyGenericStruct> and not Set< MyProtocol>.

Comment: @DavidCoufal If you just would like to make extension on `Set<MyGenericStrut>` only. You can do like my updated answer.

Comment: This answer is for `MyGenericStruct: MyProtocol`, but the stated problem is for `MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>`, which is different. The `Set` extension does not help.

Comment: @DavidCoufal if `MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>` has to be kept, how about another approach in [UPDATED2]? The main idea is to have `$0.string` be taken into account :)

Answer (score 1):

### Details

Swift 3.1, xCode 8.3.3

### Solution

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct:Hashable {

    let string: String

    static func == (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.string == rhs.string
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return string.hash
    }
}

extension Set where Element == MyStruct {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {
        return filter({ $0.string == string }).first
    }
}

var set = Set<MyStruct>()
set.insert(MyStruct(string: "123"))
set.insert(MyStruct(string: "231"))
print(String(describing:set.getFirstWith(string: "123")))
print(String(describing:set.getFirstWith(string: "231")))

///////////////////////////////////

protocol MyProtocol {}

struct MyType1: MyProtocol {}
struct MyType2: MyProtocol {}

struct MyGenericStruct<T: MyProtocol>: Hashable {
    let string: String

    static func == (lhs: MyGenericStruct, rhs: MyGenericStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.string == rhs.string
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return string.hash
    }
}

extension Set where Element == AnyHashable {
    func getFirstWith(string: String) -> Element? {


        return filter{ element -> Bool in
            if let _element = element as? MyGenericStruct<MyType1> {
                if  _element.string == string {
                    return true
                }
            }
            if let _element = element as? MyGenericStruct<MyType2> {
                if  _element.string == string {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }.first

    }
}

var set2 = Set<AnyHashable>()
set2.insert(MyGenericStruct<MyType1>(string: "abc"))
set2.insert(MyGenericStruct<MyType2>(string: "cba"))
print(String(describing: set2.getFirstWith(string: "abc")))
print(String(describing:set2.getFirstWith(string: "cba")))
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: This is cool, but depends on the Set extension knowing about all possible MyProtocol types.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here on request.

I was unable to figure out how to make this an extension on `Set`.

Instead, we wrote a little utility function. Not as clear as a extension, but gets the work done. It looks like this:

```
func getFirst<T: MyProtocol>(fromSet set: Set<MyGenericStruct<T>>, whereStringIs string: String) -> MyGenericStruct<T>? {
    return set.first(where: { $0.string == string })
}
```

As others have noted, `MyGenericStruct` needs to be Hashable.